# Equality of array of object irrespective of index by value not by reference

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, jasmine

I'm using the following versions:

```
"jasmine-core": "~2.8.0", 
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1", 
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0", 
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2", 
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
```

Call me stupid but I need this. Equality by value not by reference

```
function isEqual(var1, var2) {
  //....
  // return true or false
}
```

Test:

```
isEqual(1,1) // true
isEqual("Test", "Test") // true
isEqual([1,2,3], [3,2,1]) // true   => irrespective of array index
isEqual({a:1, b:2}, {b:2, a:1}) // true
isEqual([{a:1}, {b:2}], [{b:2}, {a:1}]) // true
isEqual([1,2, {a:{b:2}}], [2,1, {a:{b:2}}]) // true
isEqual([{a:[1,2], b:10}], [{b:10, a:[2,1]}]) // true
```

Background: I am using Jasmin for Angular testing. Getting difficulties in checking 
equality of object by value. `expect().toEqual()` check equality of object type. I want to compare array of object irrespective of array index.

What I get:

```
expect([{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }]).toEqual([{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }]); // true 
expect([{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }]).toEqual([{ b: 2 }, { a: 1 }]); // false
```

What I want :

```
expect([{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }]).toEqual([{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }]); // true 
expect([{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }]).toEqual([{ b: 2 }, { a: 1 }]); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `toDeepEqual`

```
expect([{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }]).toDeepEqual([{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }]);
expect([{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }]).toDeepEqual([{ b: 2 }, { a: 1 }]);
```

Comment: ```Property 'toDeepEqual' does not exist on type 'ArrayLikeMatchers<{ a: number; } | { b: number; }>'```

Comment: What's the version of Jasmine that you're using?

Comment: ```"jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1","karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2", "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",```